# SQL Server Full BackUP functionality

Tags: sql-server, sql

In SQL Server 2008 R2 (or Any other Version);
**Transaction-1** had started at 11:50:00 and it takes 1hr.5min to complete(i.e., completed at 12:55:00) and
**Transaction-2** had started at 17:45:00 and it takes 1hr to complete(i.e., completed at 18:45:00)..
And i had scheduled Full Backup at 12:00:00 and time taken to complete the back up was 6.0 hrs(i.e completed at 18:00:00).
So, How does the Full BackUp functions and what transactions does it contains.?

Answer (score 3):

A [Full backup](http://sqlbak.com/academy/full-backup/) is the simplest kind of SQL Server backup. It provides a complete copy of the database but allows restoring the database only to a point-in-time when the backup was made. A full database backup backs up all data files and active part of the transaction log. The active part of the transaction log is necessary to restore a database to a transactionally consistent point.

A full database backup doesn’t contain all records from your transaction log. Instead, it chooses only those records that are necessary to make the restored copy of the database transactionally consistent. Those records begin either from the latest active transaction or from the checkpoint created by the backup.

So in your case, a full backup will contain Transaction 1, try to add to your backup plan a transaction log backups.

Comment: Actually no, it will not. Tx 1 has not completed at the beginning of the backup.

Comment: @TomTom but it will, till the full backup ends, so a full backup will contain it.